# the result of json format, (error code 3, Invalid parameter)

Tags: steam-web-api

but i got this result failed as json format like this below,

> > > > 

{"response":{"error":{"errorcode":3,"errordesc":"Invalid parameter"}}}

> > > > > 

let me know, which problem caused it?

please save me..........

iam trying to apply the steam api especially something related to authentication.

i attempted checking that this api works well via web browser crome like this below,

> > > > > 

https://partner.steam-api.com/ISteamUserAuth/AuthenticateUserTicket/v1/?key=6E6465828A1E76A5E9745E254181D747&appid=120&ticket=100091a58e6cbaf510114556100010002000b2a9c396bd6e1000b00030004000baf51011c420186dc1ac00003966b4761078b01083200000ac41b8df9e94ccbb41bcf24cdb58b79212a38c25e62426b9863be37f29622ff51e926d2227ce4ca9d1b5d28af8c9df83f3f7223db3d8ca6c3e4be94d888b47bc

> > > > 

i have checked many thing that i am suspicious of cause.

by this checking,
i think AppID, WebAPI Key are correct.

by any chance, the state of our game which is Unavailable state(App Release State) could be a problem???
(our game number is 2114250)

please save me..........i am dying....